# Static IntPtr access into and out of anonymous method

Tags: c#, static, out

A (global) static IntPtr var is passed to a p/invoke DLL interop call which places a valid handle to a USB device in regular code into that var.

`private static IntPtr commHandle = (IntPtr)0;`

When the USB device is hung or in a strange state, that call to the interop code waits for reply – endlessly. To avoid an application hang, I put the code into an anonymous method thread (below) inside of the normal method, and although the call to open the port works, using the returned handle results in errors – the same kind of errors you’d get if the port wasn’t opened in the first place.

```
public IntPtr OpenPort(int deviceID)
Thread weAreAnonymous = new Thread(() => 
{
    if( 0==(int)commHandle)
    {
        var res = dllCommOpen(deviceID, out commHandle);
    } 
    if ((int)res > 0)
    {
        dllComFlush(res);
        this.IsOpen = ((int)res != 0);
    }
});

weAreAnonymous.Start();
```

Now we wait for a short time for thread to open the port. If the thread is still running after a short nap, we know that the port open failed and can handle accordingly...
Only, the returned handle while appearing to be valid, doesn't seem to really point to an open port!

Comment: Assuming that this compile, it looks like the `res` in the second `if` is not the same `res` as you get from `dllCommOpen`: that one is local to the block of the first `if`.

Comment: BTW: Casting a 64-bit pointer to a 32-bit integer is not a good idea. Use [IntPtr.Zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero.aspx) instead.

Comment: Yeah, I had issues with the Stackoverflow editor, ignore the var res - the salient issue at hand is why a STATIC variable is in a kind of not-quite-there state when put into the arms of an anonymous method.